# PictureBox - Opacity paint inside given coordinates

Tags: vb.net, paint, picturebox

I have a Picturebox and inside that I want to paint (with opacity to don't full hide the painted region) a determinated region of the picture with the coordniates given.

So far I've the 'IF' statement to when user click the picturebox it checks if is the region with the correct coordinates:

```
If LocalMousePosition.X >= 87 And LocalMousePosition.X <= 131 And LocalMousePosition.Y >= 5 And LocalMousePosition.Y <= 55 Then

            Label1.Text = "coordinate correct"
        Else
            Label1.Text = ""

End If
```

Now I've no idea how to paint the clicked region.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like...

[image: Highlighted Rectangle via Paint() Event]

```
Public Class Form1

    Private InTarget As Boolean = False
    Private Target As New Rectangle(New Point(87, 5), New Size(45, 51))

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        Dim clientCoords As Point = PictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
        InTarget = Target.Contains(clientCoords)
        Label1.Text = IIf(InTarget, "coordinate correct", "")
        PictureBox1.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
        If InTarget Then
            Using highlight As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Yellow)) ' 0 to 255
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(highlight, Target)
            End Using
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Wow Idle_Mind you are a genius, again you helped me find a solution! You helped me in this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418145/picturebox-get-image-inside-drawn-rectangle-and-show-in-another-picturebox
Thank you so much!

Comment: That's fine.  Don't worry about it.  I can't remember at what reputation levels you can do specific things at.